# С "паскаль стайл" на с++

Tags: c++, c

Только начинаю изучать с++ и поэтому по старой привычке индексирую элементы массива образом указанным ниже, прошу подсказать как организовать индексацию "по уму" что бы это выглядело более приемлемо для языка С. Заранее спасибо.

```
void Calculations()
{
int min;
int id=0;

for (int i=1; i<m; i+=2)
{
    min = matr[i][0];
    for (int j=1; j<n; j++)
    {
        if (matr[i][j] < min) min = matr[i][j];
    }
    if (min<0){ mas[id]=min;id++; }
}
```

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Формально все вроде бы правильно.

Если добавить 

    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int matr[20][20], mas[20], m, n;

и `}` в конце, то вообще компилируется (g++).

Comment: программа работает правильно, но мне сказали что вот такой способо индексирования {if (matr[i][j] < min) min = matr[i][j];} не по стилю к с++, как я понимаю речь идет об индексировании способом (*(*matrix+j)+i), прошу подсказать как реализовать это без ущерба программе

Comment: Фигню Вам сказали. Нормальный стиль. Для работы с простыми двумерными массивами - вполне пригоден.

Comment: проблема в том что сказал мне это препод, и мне  любом случае придется подстроиться под его условия

Comment: >проблема в том что сказал мне это препод

тогда это может послужить для вас сигналом, что этому преподу не стоит безоговорочно доверять, и те или иные его слова нужно воспринимать со здравой долей скептицизма

Comment: @Алексей Першин, если размерность массива определена на стадии компиляции, то стиль matrix[i][j] самый нормальный.

Но(!!!) Если размер динамический или матрица передается в функцию вместе с количеством строк и столбцов, т.е.

     void calc (int *matr, int rows, int cols);
     ...
     int matrix[n][m];
     ...
       calc(matrix, n, m);

то стиль  `*((matrix+ (i * cols)) + j)` внутри `calc()` становится единственно возможным (где i - номер строки, а j - столбца).

Просто Ваш преподаватель, сказав А не успел произнести остальные (необходимые для понимания темы) буквы.

Comment: avp спасибо, если не трудно не могли бы вы показать наглядно на этом примере как его использовать. программа работает и сейчас, но нужно изменить этот способ.

Comment: Значит так. В современном C++принято индексировать массивы по-человечески: `array[index]`. «Индексация» посредством адресной арифметики (`*(array + index)`) считается нечитаемым кодом и просто плохим стилем.

Подстраиваться под препода с квалификацией на уровне первокурсника не советую. То, что так в принципе _можно_ писать, не означает, что _нужно_. Для написания нечитаемого кода должны быть **очень** веские основания.

Comment: >То, что так в принципе можно писать, не означает, что нужно

в крестах вообще немало того, что в общем-то можно, но неприемлемо в или нежелательно в реальных проектах

Comment: Если звездочки режут глаз, а душа требует квадратных скобочек


    void calc(int matr[], int rows, int cols) {
       ....
       matr[i * cols + j] = ...;

Но это все уже из области holywars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы чуть улучшил. Примерно так:

```
void computeSomething() {

  int min = 0;
  int id = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i < m; i+=2)
  {
      min = matrix[i][0];
      for (int j=1; j < n; j++) {
          if (matrix[i][j] < min) { // [оптимизация]
            min = matrix[i][j]; // [оптимизиация]
          }
      }
      if ( min < 0) {
        result[id] = min;
        id++; 
      }
}
```

Остальное пока не решился. Вопросы по коду:

- Если к Вам позвонят когда Вы будете на море и спросят "что такое m, n, id в твоем коде?". Вы сможете ответить не долго думая? Есть ли у Вас какие-либо общепринятые имена, которые Вы всегда юзаете?
- Переименуйте matrix на более осмысленное!
- Переименуйте m, n, id на что-то адекватное

Что Вы не учли:

- Инициализация min в самом начале
- Наименование дали такими чтобы при поиски баги в вашем коде человек как можно больше помучался. Представьте что в Вашей компании при комите в репозитарий в каждый исходник проставляется полный адрес авторов и модификаторов кода и что следующие программисты будут знать куда бежать и применят биту;
- Не проставили фигурные скобки. Даже для одинарных действий это имеет значение. Помогает при отладке, легко поставить printf и поставить бряк;

Если уж совсем быть дотошным, чтобы разжевать тривиальные вещи, то :

- Участок кода с for(int j ... .вполне можно вынести в отдельную функцию, представьте что вы пишете комментарий. Вот так ее и назовите
- Внутри этого же кода участок с if(matrix[][] < min .. вынести в отдельный метод conditionalSomething();
- Участок кода с if в самом конце тоже в отдельный метод;

*Вопрос* "Правильно ли стоят min, id ?"

*Ответ*: Да. Они объявлены сразу же как понадобились. *Метрика*: как правило переменная должна быть объявлена в пределах 5 строк, если же дальше, значит вы слишком многобукв написал и следует код разбить на более мелкие функции.

Не надо уподобляться советскому периоду и его названиям "ГЛАВСТРОЙНАХМАШ" или "СОВРАЙТРАСТНАХ" или еще чего-нить. Пишите как можно проще!

P.S.:
Про оптимизацию: "matrix[i][j]", можно вытащить в: "int *curLine = matrix[i];" итогда можно будет адресоваться как: "curLine[j]"

Comment: Принципиальная ошибка и этого кода и кода автора вопроса состоит в том, что воспользоваться результатом `void computeSomething()` не очень-то просто.

--

Поясню.

В результате работы получаем массив (result[]) отрицательных минимумов нечетных столбцов матрицы. Этот массив внешний по отношению к функции. 

А вот количество заполненных элементов в нем остается внутри (`int id` локальная).

Единственным разумным способом будет заполнение всех элементов result, например, нулями перед вызовом `computeSomething()` и его анализ на отрицательные величины после вызова.

--

Вывод: *возвращайте id !*

Comment: В данном случае я предпочел не возвращать id, по одной простой причине задача метода "Подсчитать", а не "Вернуть". Дело в том что надо стремиться описать одним действием относящемуся к данному уровню абстракции, чтобы избежать каких-либо вопросов от читающего код. Если все-таки вернуть хочется, то отразить это в названии метода к примеру computeSomethingAndGetId(). Нельзя заставлять читающего код задавать вопросы "Да где ж это происходит-то?". Скажу что грешен, у меня тоже много гуанкода ;))) Но тем не менее ;)

Comment: @sys_dev, хорошие названия, без сомнения лучше плохих, но все-таки качество кода зависит от них не настолько, как это преподносят в книжках типа "Чистый код", "Совершенный код" и т.п.

IMHO лучше удобная для использования какая-нибудь `int negminrows(int *matrix, int rows, int cols, int result[])`, чем абсолютно самоописывающий себя одним названием, но требующий при работе с ним пяти лишних строк кода (утрирую...) метод.

--

Кстати, Вы обратили внимание, что основная проблема с пониманием у автора связана с матрицами неизвестной во время компиляции размерностью (см. в комментариях к вопросу)

Comment: @avp, Конечно обратил. Автор не увидел проблему из-за непонятного кода. Мы часто "видя книгу видим фигу". За много лет Reversing-Engineering-а привык много экспериментировать и очень многое что было взято на пробу из книг Фаулера и МакКонела так и продолжает "пробоваться" до сих пор перейдя в разряд "Ежедневная практика". Рекомендую взять свой код, убраь из него всякое упоминание о Вашем авторстве и пойти к гуру, которого Вы очень уважаете и чье мнение цените. Скажите что этот код содержит багу и никак не понять как фиксить. Оценка вашего кода - время за которое Ваш знакомый пофиксит багу

Comment: @sys_dev, интересные мысли:)

"Багу" самому вносить или оставить код как есть?

И потом не забывайте старую шутку - каждая исправленная ошибка вносит по крайней мере еще одну.

--

А насчет "не увидел проблему из-за непонятного кода" (к автору не относится), так обычно наоборот - если человек осознает все проблемы, то и код он пишет красивый.

Answer (score 1):

почитайте код ниже думаю разберетесь

```
int main(){
  // ОБЪЯВЛЕНИЕ МАССИВОВ

  // 1. обычное обьявление
  int array_one[10][10];
  // 2. с использованием макроподстановки (с человеческим лицом)
  #define FIRST_INDEX 10
  #define SECOND_INDEX 10
  int array_two[FIRST_INDEX][SECOND_INDEX];
  // 3. с использованием констант (C++ метод)
  const int FIRST_INDEX_CONST = 10;
  const int SECOND_INDEX_CONST = 10;
  int array_three[FIRST_INDEX_CONST][SECOND_INDEX_CONST];

  // ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕ МАССИВОВ

  // для работы с индексами массива можно использовать
  // 1. имена переменных с целым типом или сам литерал (число)
  int x = 5;
  array_one[x][5] = 555;
  // 2. любое выражение возвращающие целое число
  int y;
  array_one[x + 1][y = x - 1] = 333;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вот за `#define`-константы в XXI веке можно (нужно) бы и наказывать.

Comment: согласен но чужие коды тоже читать уметь надо

Comment: @alexlz, помнится, я когда-то много читал о вреде `#define`, но что-то никто не смог безоговорочно убедить меня в их безусловной вредности по сравнению с `const`.

Может у Вас получиться?

Основной аргумент против `const` это то, что C и C++ по разному их трактуют (в смысле области видимости при линковке нескольких модулей). Т.е. использование `const` напрочь привязывает проект к крестам (со всеми вытекющими...)

Comment: @avp Ну о разнице видимости const я даже не думал. Основное возражение -- макропроцессор работает до всех контролей и разборов (в т.ч. и блоки ему пофиг -- он их не знает) Напр:

    #include <stdio.h>
    #define a 1
    int main() {
        {
    #define a 2
        }
      printf("%d", a);
      return 0;
    }

(Правда gcc меня предупредил. Сейчас. Когда я на эти грабли наступил, то предупреждения не видел или не заметил). Почти вся диагностика макропроцессор игнорирует (а если использовать cpp -- тем более). А использовал тогда protothreads, которые суть библиотека макросов.

Comment: @alexlz, само собой, компилятор про `#define` ничего не знает, да и отладчик (по крайней мере gdb) про них ничего не знает. 

И это естественно, если их не рассматривать, как часть языка. Просто относитесь к ним как к препроцессору (т.е. смотрите на то, что есть на самом деле). И соответственно планируйте отладку.

Против `enum` возражений (кроме того, что лично я их плохо помню) у меня как раз нет.

А вот проблемы с линковкой констант...

Comment: @alexlz, наверное я как-то невнятно написал о `enum` в предыдущем комментарии.

Или Вы имеете в виду `extern const enum myenum x;` в одном файле и
`const enum myenym x = ENUMVALUE;` в области глобальной видимости в другом?

Естественно та же проблема, что и с int (и любым типом). 

В gcc это будет собираться, а g++ нет.


В принципе решается условной компиляцией. Если все модули делать одним компайлером, то достаточно 

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern 
    #endif
    const enum myenum x = B;

в модуле где константе присваивается значение. 

*(NB! тут опять неявный `#define __cplusplus`)*

Comment: @avp я имел в виду enum в хедерах

     avp.h:
     enum {avp=1};

     avp.c++:
     #include <iostream>
     #include "avp.h"
     int main() {
       std::cout << avp << std::endl;
       return 0;
     }

Просто `enum`, в отличие от `#define` -- элемент языка.

Comment: @alexlz, а какие тут могут быть проблемы? 

IMHO все нормально. Только в таком виде enum-ы мало отличаются от define-ов. 

Со смесью модулей (С, С++) тоже все ОК (конечно, надо не забывать `extern "C"` перед прототипами функций, транслируемых gcc). 

И отладчик показывает символьное (а не число) значение.


--

Только, наверное лучше их именовать. Т.е.

    .h
    enum alexlz {alexlz, avp, vladd = 100};

    .c
    void foo(enum alexlz x) { printf("Кто это %d у нас?\n", x); }

Answer (score -1):

В С и С++ первый элемент массива имеет индекс 0. А дальше сами попробуйте поправить Ваш текст.

Comment: >В С и С++ первый элемент массива имеет индекс 0

да и вообще практически везде, корме Паскаля

Comment: В Фортране, кажись, можно вообще указывать, с какого индекса начинается нумерация элементов массива.

Comment: @mikillskegg ну вроде начиная с f77. В f4 нижняя граница индекса не задавалась и была равна 1.

Comment: Я с фортраном ниже f77 дело не имел )))